# Finding PDF of function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ has PDF:

$f_X (x)= \lambda e^{-\lambda(x+2)}$ , for $x \ge-2$

$f_X(x)=0$ , for $x <-2$

Determine the PDF of $Y = X^2$. I am stuck because for $-2\le X \le 2$, $0\le Y \le 4$, and I don't know how to deal with this correctly. So far, I've found the CDF of $X$:

$F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda (x+2)}$, for $x \ge-2$

$F_X(x)=0$, for $x <-2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y<0$, obviously $f_Y(y)=0$.

For $+\infty>y>4$,
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(\sqrt{y})\bigg|\frac{dx}{dy}\bigg|$$
$$=\lambda e^{-\lambda(\sqrt{y}+2)}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$
$$=\frac{\lambda e^{-2\lambda}}{2}\frac{e^{-\lambda\sqrt{y}}}{\sqrt{y}}$$

For $0 \le y \le 4$,
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(\sqrt{y})\bigg|\frac{dx}{dy}\bigg|_{x=\sqrt{y}}\bigg|+f_X(-\sqrt{y})\bigg|\frac{dx}{dy}\bigg|_{x=-\sqrt{y}}\bigg|$$
$$=\lambda e^{-\lambda (\sqrt{y}+2)}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}+\lambda e^{-\lambda (-\sqrt{y}+2)}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$
$$=\frac{\lambda e^{-2\lambda}}{2}\frac{e^{-\lambda \sqrt{y}}+e^{\lambda \sqrt{y}}}{\sqrt{y}}$$